# MongoDB - pipeline grouping by unique set?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, query-performance

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
{
   "model":"1234",
   "trackingNumber":"9123..."
}
```

These models values are shared by very many records, and I'm trying to find which combinations represent the most common groupings.

I have a pipeline that gives me what I want, but order matters there. For example:

```
{
   "_id":["1234","4321"]
   "count":69761
},
{
   "_id":["4321","1234"]
   "count":44321
},
...
```

Is there any way to use _id to group by unique arrays, regardless of order?
The only solution I have thought of so far is sort by the model and hoping that preserve `$addToSet` operation order, but that both feels hacky and feels low performance and I don't suspect order of operations is guaranteed anyways.

My pipeline:

```
db.trackingIds.aggregate([
      
     {
        $match: { $and: [
                ...
           ] }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : "$trackingNumber",
            models: {$addToSet: "$model"},
            count : { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : "$models",
            count : { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            count:  -1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might `$unwind` the array, sort by the unwound values, then `$group` by `_id` and `$push` the elements back into an array.

That way the array is sorted, so the various equivalent sets should test equal.